# Can't play songs from bundle with iPodMusicPlayer in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediaitemcollection

I am trying to play songs from bundle(document directory) in my app with `iPodMusicPlayer`.

I don't want to play with `AVPlayer`.

Here is some of my code:

```
NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
        NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSArray *dirContents = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundleRoot error:nil];
        NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.mp3'"];
        NSArray *onlyMP3 = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr];
        self.app.arrayFromAppDelegate = [onlyMP3 mutableCopy];

        NSLog(@"%i",self.app.arrayFromAppDelegate.count);

        self.userMediaItemCollection = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:self.app.arrayFromAppDelegate];
        NSLog(@"Collection count is : %i",self.userMediaItemCollection.count);

        [self.player setQueueWithItemCollection:self.userMediaItemCollection];
        [self.player setNowPlayingItem:(MPMediaItem *)[self.app.arrayFromAppDelegate objectAtIndex:0]];

[self.player play];
```

First I retrieve all mp3s from the documents directory and add them into an `NSMutableArray`.

And then I add them into an `MPMediaItemCollection` and setQueue to play.
Then I play.

But when I play, it's only showing `MediaPlayer: Message nowPlayingItem timed out in iOS`.

I am okay when I play songs from the iPod Library with the above code.

But I can't play songs from the App Bundle.

`NSLog` method also shows the correct count of songs from the documents directory.

But I can't play.

How can I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `MPMusicPlayerController`, you can't use mp3 files from the documents directory. `MPMusicPlayerController` is only compatible with items from the device iPod library.